# Spring 16 release not allowing edit of Napili template via site.com studio

Tags: community, customer-community, community-cloud

I choose Napili template in Spring 16 enabled org and try editing it to insert a HTML widget and it says "This page is based on lightning template and cannot be edited via site.com ".

The winter 16 allowed this ,so please let me know how can one edit standard templates via site.com .I have attached screenshot of the issue .

[image]

If one uses site.com how do i import all the templates and functionalities of the existing templates ? Please share your thoughts on this .

Comment: Are you using Napoli templates from prior to W16? If so, that could be the problem. Support for them died, umm ended that is, with SP16.

Comment: No its new template from spring 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got response from salesforce community cloud expert team here

> Need to be using the Community builder to work with Lightning Templates. You should upgrade your site.com templates to lightning templates.

**Site.com templates will not be supported after the Summer release.**

**With Spring 16, Site.com is only needed for uploading / managing assets, multi-lingual features, and debugging.**